# Как сделать кросдоменный запрос с Authorization?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

запущенны 2 nodeJS сервера, с одного делаю ajax-запрос ко второму:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3030/data.json', {  
    method: 'get',              
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer abc"
    }
})
.then( (response)=>response.json() )
.then(function (data) {  
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);  
})  
.catch(function (error) {  
    console.log('Request failed', error);  
});
```

изза `Authorization` браузер должен сделать 2 запроса OPTIONS и GET

но на OPTIONS возвращается:

> Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3030/data.json. Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```html
General:
Request URL:http://localhost:3030/data.json
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3030
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
access-control-allow-headers:content-type, accept
access-control-allow-methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:http://localhost:3000
access-control-max-age:10
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 26 Apr 2017 14:31:58 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Express

Request Headers:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3030
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
```

помогите настроить ответ с сервера чтоб ajax-запрос работал без ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В заголовках ответа Access-Control-Allow-Headers надо разрешить Authorization